# Get param names in a infinite parameter function

Tags: php, debugging

Im trying to create a debug function which write parameters into a file.

The function currently looks like this

```
function file_debug($path){
    //skip the first parameter 
    $skip_first = true;
    foreach (func_get_args() as $param) {
        if($skip_first){
            $skip_first = false;
            continue;
        }
        $backtrace = debug_backtrace()[0];
        file_put_contents($path, "[".date("Y-m-d H:i:s")."] ".$backtrace['file']." ".$backtrace['line'].PHP_EOL);
    }
}
```

It would be nice for the function to also include the name of the parameters as well. I did a bit research and all the functions(`get_defined_vars()`, `ReflectionFunction($funcName)`) I found does not suit for this job. 
As far as I know, `get_defined_vars()` is not very reliable and `ReflectionFunction($funcName)` can only be used out side the function.

I need to get the parameters name **inside the function** which makes the `ReflectionFunction` not a suitable solution.

Please note that this function is designed to take **infinite number of parameters**. The function would not know the names of all the parameters come after that `$path`.

Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: @NateB As i mentioned in the question, ReflectionFunction is only suitable when you are outside the function. I want the parameters name inside this function. So it is not a duplication. Thanks.

Comment: It seemed like the accepted answer in that post would definitely apply to your situation. Apologies if I'm missing something here.

Comment: @NateB My function takes infinite number of parameters, the accepted answer only takes 1 parameters. The difference is i dont have a $funcName handy, all i have is the first parameter which is $path, the parameters come after that this function would have no clue about them.

Comment: Flag removed; sorry bout that!

Comment: @NateB lol, You reminded me that i didnt state that clear enough. Thanks